# array randomization accuracy of the decision tree vs fisher yates shuffle algorithm

Tags: algorithm, decision-tree, fisher-yates-shuffle

now I want to know about the accuracy of the randomization of the decision tree and fisher yates algorithms. if the two algorithms are compared how do i find out?

I tried to find references about the comparison of the two algorithms but couldn't find it.

Comment: Elaborate on "the decision tree" algorithm and what you mean by "accuracy". Assuming a proper random source, it can be proven that all permutations are equiprobable when using Fisher-Yates.

Comment: yah, the decision tree has the disadvantage of being unstable, but how can I prove it if the decision tree is better than fisher yates
is there a graph about the two algorithms?